# Use Provider to provide BLoCs globally to whole flutter module

Tags: flutter, provider

https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Can I use Provider to provide blocs globally to all widgets down the tree without MaterialApp? I tried to provide BLoC to a page, but when I'm navigating to the next page, BloC isn't found. So should I provide it whenever I'm navigating to a new page or is there a solution to provide it globally without MaterialApp?

Currently I'm doing it this way

```
Provider
|_MaterialApp
  |_MyPage1 (from which you can navigate to MyPage2...3)
```

This approach works, and all pages can access provided BLoC.

But if use this approach

```
Provider
  |_MyPage1 (from which you can navigate to MyPage2...3)
```

MyPage2, MyPage3 can't find provided BLoC. BLoC only can be found on MyPage1

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by using the `builder` property of a `MaterialApp`.

**lib/main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SomeBloc {
  final String someValue;

  SomeBloc(this.someValue);

  void dispose() {}
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  SomeBloc _someBloc = SomeBloc("someValue");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, widget) => Provider<SomeBloc>(
        create: (_) => _someBloc,
        dispose: (_, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
        child: widget,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/first-page',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/first-page': (context) => FirstPage(),
        '/second-page': (context) => SecondPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SomeBloc _someBloc = Provider.of<SomeBloc>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_someBloc.someValue),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Open second page"),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => SecondPage(),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SomeBloc _someBloc = Provider.of<SomeBloc>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(_someBloc.someValue),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Per the documentation,

**home**

> The difference between using home and using builder is that the home subtree is inserted into the application **below** a Navigator.

**builder**

> ... the widget returned from builder is inserted **above** the app's Navigator (if any).

If you want your "blocs" to be provided on all of your routes, you have to provide those above the `Navigator` widget.

That's why this simply works:

```dart
return Provider(
  create: (_) => _someBloc,
  child: MaterialApp(
    home: FirstPage(),
  ),
);
```

In this setup above, `Provider` is on top of the `Navigator` widget.

And this doesn't:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  home: Provider(
    create: (_) => _someBloc,
    child: FirstPage(),
  ),
);
```

`_someBloc` will only be accessible to the `FirstPage` widget.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are there any drawbacks to providing a Bloc globally, rather than only in the widgets or screens in which it will be utilised?